# Using Axios over HTML Forms

Tags: reactjs, forms, axios, request, multipartform-data

I have a signup route with file uploads. On the frontend, however, I don't know if I should use axios or HTML forms. I don't also know if there is a way to use both accurately.

Using form will help me in terms of sending the data as muultipart/form-data. Howver, when I get a response, it will be in the URL.

Is avoiding HTML forms in such a case and sending requests manually using Axios a common practice?